# How do you markup a date range with the HTML5 time tag?

Tags: date, time, tags, html

When marking-up dates in HTML5, I know for a single date you should use the `<time>` tag as follows

`<time datetime="2011-04-02">2nd April 2011</time>`

But how would you (or should you) markup a date range like "2nd - 4th April 2011"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It would be nice if `<time>` had a nice way of representing ranges, but you have to do something like this instead:

```
<time datetime="2011-04-02">2nd</time> - <time datetime="2011-04-04">4th April 2011</time>
```

Comment: Bruce Lawson also suggests this approach for date ranges: https://www.brucelawson.co.uk/2012/best-of-time/

Answer (score 36):

Marking up date ranges has yet to be settled at this point.
(You can see [the evolving discussion on date ranges on the WhatWG site](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/Time_element).)

**Your best bet for now is to simply use the [ISO 8601 syntax for date ranges](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_intervals) as the datetime value in a time tag. In short, just separate the two values with a forward slash.**

For example, the 2nd to the 4th of April, 2011 would be:

```
<time datetime="2011-04-02/2011-04-04">2nd&ndash;4th April 2011</time>
```

Here's a simpler example representing 2000-2010:

```
<time datetime="2000/2010">2000&ndash;2010</time>
```

Remember to [use an En dash between your dates for proper presentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#Ranges_of_values).

Comment: The one drawback of this recommendation is that if, for example, you're marking up content for a Schema.org schema (say, one that requires a startDate and endDate), there's no way to specify which date is the startDate and which is the endDate. The accepted answer is kludgier but suffices better for that kind of purpose.

Comment: This is not valid HTML: `Bad value 2011-04-02/2011-04-04 for attribute datetime on element time: The literal did not satisfy the time-datetime format.`.