# correct notation of css text indent

Tags: css

**Problem:**

I have to indent my text. I have had a lot of problems with it, so I need to learn how to do it correctly now. On the desktop version the indent is looking fine. The problem is when I see on a responsive point of view, all the text is going out of control. Here is the version I have now:

[image]

Here is the version after I do a text indent on an iPhone 5 with the CSS below:

[image]

**Code:**

```
  feature-bar {
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    text-decoration: solid;
    color: red;
    text-indent: 100px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

**Question:**

How do I do a correct text indent, so it is also looking correct on a mobile?

**UPDATE**

After the answers I found out I can use `<li>` or `vw`. On a mobile point of view wanted that the clock 13.00 - 13.20 should stay on one line, and the text should start on the other line. Should I make a mediaquery with something for solving this?

**SECOND UPDATE**

Example on how it should look on mobile
[image]

Comment: Why not use media queries to apply the right amount for desktop tablet and mobile resolution?

Comment: Hello Rudi. Because there must be an eaiser way instead of sitting an adjust each phone horizontal and vertical view because of an text-indent.

Comment: This is tabluar data...why not use a table?

Comment: A clarification: the `<li>` and `vw` are addressing two different things. Using an unordered list (the `<ul>` with child `<li>`s) is about the semantics of the html (as @Paulie_D says, from your example content a table would also be semantic), basically just a question of how nice your code is - in theory it could all be `<div>`s or anything else, but experienced frontend developers will think "yuck!" // The `vw` is a relative unit ("[percentage of] **v**iewport **w**idth"). Relative units are useful, and *might* be something you end up using here, but that's harder to control (I recommend px)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of pixels, use viewport units , specificallyuse `vw` which is `viewport width` which will decrease as the width of the screen gets smaller

see here more [CSS Units](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)

see snippet below :

or better see here > **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b1x6mk4j/)** ( you can resize here better )

```css
.feature-bar {
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    text-decoration: solid;
    color: red;
    text-indent: 10vw;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="feature-bar">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, aenean sed egestas ultricies eget ornare, luctus proin malesuada. A ac lacinia. Vulputate molestie suspendisse nullam. Ornare velit ac vitae, duis duis, ac diam pede netus. Ipsum nibh ipsum, phasellus id quis vitae consectetuer blandit dolor. 
</div>
<div class="feature-bar">
Nec nulla placerat aliquam nulla urna tellus, ac ligula imperdiet, facilisis laoreet nec egestas, porttitor ante, wisi blandit sit erat. Vestibulum fermentum ac. Amet augue, mattis nec integer lorem lorem. Neque enim, pulvinar leo lorem donec, ac in. Etiam nec vestibulum justo praesent mi, pharetra praesent erat enim et purus sed, vel porttitor morbi voluptatem ante pellentesque ligula. In interdum tellus elit volutpat, purus gravida vitae vivamus ante quis, at amet, urna scelerisque suspendisse quis tortor vestibulum.
</div>
```

UPDATE after your edit to the question .

use lists :

careful, `ul` has a default padding , change it to `padding-left:5vw` so it will get smaller when you resize the window

see snippet below or fiddle here : **[jsfiddle with list](https://jsfiddle.net/b1x6mk4j/3/)**

```css
ul {padding-left:5vw}
br { display:none;} /* if you want all content of `li` to be on same row , time and text */

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) { /* mobile devices */
  
  br { display:block; } /* time on one row, text on the next rows */
  }
```

```html
<h1>
program for seminar
</h1>

<ul>
  <li>13.00 - 13.30 <br />
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, non leo arcu risus fermentum at quam. Ac tincidunt vel non, quisque at libero odio ac eu sed, lectus condimentum non scelerisque tortor ligula.
</li>
  <li >14.00 - 14.30<br />
Consectetuer diam consequat cursus fusce odio, fusce lacinia quis sit, sed etiam consequat pulvinar. Ut nisl, sed vulputate, dui ut pede varius in aenean, blandit accumsan pellentesque.
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So no matter which size of screen the text would fit? I tried to see the fiddle. If I wanted to set a padding-left would that also work, and I padding-right, so the text is not going over the edge?

it is actually not the text-indent I have to use I can see. Rather the padding

Comment: well `text-indent` does something, `padding` does a different thing.  you need to choose one of them ...depending on what you want to achieve... `.feature-bar { text-indent:1000px}` will make the first line of text be indented ( have a `margin-left`  of )  1000px . whereas `.feature-bar { padding-left:1000px}` will move 1000px from left to right ALL the content inside that div ( text,img whatever ) not only the first line

Comment: Thank you again for your answer. I actually wants all the text to go in, so that would be margin I had to use here. On a mobile point of view, I would like the text started under the clock. I just updated my question if you have time to look at it, I would be really happy.

Comment: oh. so `text-indent` has nothing to do with what you want. i edited my answer. let me know if it helps

Comment: No I misunderstood appartly what I actually needed I can see. Sorry for that. Isnt there a way, where I can set the breakline online on mobile portrait view?

Comment: you mean to hide the break line when on desktop , and only show it when on mobile ? if YES , then use `li br { display:none;}`  ( text will get all on one line ) and then `@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) { br {display:block}  } `  ( text will go on separate lines )

Comment: Uh it is so hard to explain. I just took a screenshot of what I mean and posted in my question again. But yes so only on mobile there is a break line between the time and the text. I am just gonna post the example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122212/discussion-between-mihai-t-and-mads-kristensen).

Comment: changed my answer. added some comments too . hope it's ok now. it looks just like in your screenshot

Answer (score 2):

The standard solution would be using left padding. Don't know what your HTML is like, but this would be something like

```css
ul {
  padding-left: 100px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  outline: 1px solid red;/* just for demo purposes to reveal the padding */
}
li {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<p>Heading</p>
<ul>
  <li>first item, showing what it looks like when an item wraps to more than one line asdf asdf asdf asdf sdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf</li>
  <li>qwer</li>
</ul>
```

If you want extra vertical space around the list, you could do one of two things. Here I'm making the total space at the bottom of the `ul` 30px

```
ul {
    padding-bottom: 10px;/* is in addition to the 20px from the last li */
}
```

or

```
ul {
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}
li:last-child {
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

(The second option can be more reliable: you don't have to think about the math, and the person working on the site doesn't have to remember/know that the last `li` is contributing padding. Not a big deal in a simple case like this, but useful to keep in mind in cases where the css is more involved)

No matter what you do, you'll probably want to do something like `.some-class-name` and `.some-class-name li` instead of the bare `ul` and `li` in my examples - otherwise this will style *every* list on your site!

Note that I'm using bottom padding rather than top - that isn't strictly necessary, but I find favoring bottom padding and bottom margin (as opposed to top) a good habit to get into. Knowing that spacing is almost certainly coming from the upper thing can make things easier to debug and/or adjust

---

### Bonus

Following your update to the question: one way of putting the time on its own line on mobile: wrap the time in some element that displays inline on desktop and block on mobile. `span` is `display: inline` by default, making it a handy choice here. A generic solution would be

```
<li>
    <span>mobile own line</span> other stuff
</li>
```

```css
@media (max-width: yyypx) {
    span {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

where yyy is your mobile break point. Again, that will probably be `.some-class-name span`.

Because this is a time value, you can be all beautifully semantic with the `time` element:

```
<li><time datetime="13:00/13:30">13:00&ndash;13:30<time> other stuff</li>
```

and then target the `time` in the css (see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_time_datetime.asp and https://stackoverflow.com/a/10403376/1241736)

Comment: Okay I see where you are getting at. So I could also set a `padding-right: 20px;` , so the text did not go over the edge at the right side? In case I wanted the padding more in on the left side on the desktop I could set a media Query for that?

Comment: Sure you could do that. I've updated the snippet in my answer to show that left and right spacing. Note that the `list-style: none` is just what keeps each `<li>` from starting with a • bullet

Comment: Ah okay perfect. Learned a lot here. I tried to add the code you said. I just updated my question with a screenshot. If you have time I would like you took a look at it?

Comment: Perfect that looks really good. Do you have an idea if I had to set an viewport to control the clock and the text regarding my question before?

Comment: Updated my answer - that solution is now in the "bonus" section

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the `text-indent` only applies to a new rule. Where in your phone's example, the rule gets broken and therefore, goes to the start of the div.

Change `text-indent: 100px` into `padding-left: 100px`

In case you have other content that shouldn't be aligned, wrap the content in a span / div and apply the styling to this element.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just cannot see how that should change it. When I set a padding-left, I still need to adjust all phones with media queries? I just tried it, and everything is at the right side now.

Comment: Could you post your code (preferably in a jsfiddle) so I can poke around?

Answer (score 0):

This is tabular data. Just use a table, it's semantic and requires very little maintenance or media queries.

```css
table {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  color: red;
}
table tr td {
  vertical-align: top;
}
table tr td:first-child {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>11:30 - 12:30</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum, nihil nam veniam perferendis facilis error.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>12:30 - 13:30</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>13:30 - 14:30</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste, nihil!</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```